# How to add sprite images to the anchor that also has anchor text

Tags: html, css

I am using a sprite image for anchor tag which as a anchor link as well, something like:

```
<a>Hello</a>
```

My css:

```
a:link {
  background: url(sprites.PNG) no-repeat 0 0;
  color: #F7B600 !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
```

I want to give height and width only for sprite background image. But If I set width and height for anchor, then the text for anchor takes that dimensions.

Is there any way?

Comment: Could you please add a JSFiddle or snippit?

Comment: If the sprite is for an icon then use an element inside anchor tag for the icon and give the background to that element.

Comment: I think will you tried to show a icon before the anger text?

Comment: Yes, but the anchor text should have some padding between the text and the icon

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an element inside anchor tag for the image

```css
i {
    width: 46px;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) 0 0
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><i></i>testing icon</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an extra element for the sprite icon inside your anchor tag like this

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span>Hello</span>
</a>
```

Then you need to apply the sprite styles only for the "icon" element

```
.icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(sprites.PNG) no-repeat 0 0;
}

/*This is the style for the link*/
.span {
  color: #F7B600 !important;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
```